# SAS start and end date from consecutive run

Tags: date, sas, lag, retain

I have a dataset of customers buying items in multiple batches of consecutive days over the year e.g. Customer A buys on the 1st of January, the 2nd of January and the 3rd of January, stops, then buys again on the 1st of February, the 2nd of February and the 3rd of February.

I'm looking to capture the first and last date of each consecutive batch for each customer (so the usual MIN / MAX will miss out of batches in between dates).

I've experimented with RETAIN and LAG and I'm getting close but its not quite what I want.

How do I create a query that will display two rows for Customer A? i.e. row 1 showing start date of the 1st of January and end date of the 3rd of January; row 2 showing start date of the 1st of February and end date of the 3rd of February.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking to group the values based on the presence of a gap between the dates.  So test for that and create a new group number variable.  Then you can use that new grouping variable in your analysis.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by id date;
  dif_days = dif(sales_date);
  if first.id then group=1;
  else if dif_days > 1 then group+1;
run;
```

You can adjust the number of days in the last IF statement to adjust how large of a gap you want to allow and still consider the events as part of the same group.

Comment: Tom - thanks! You've answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: If I could be so bold and ask a follow up? What would you do if you had sales dates captured on one row showing start 1st of January and end 3rd of January, then another row showing start the 4th of January and end the 6th of January? How would I condense these to show one row with a start date of the 1st of January and an end date of the 6th of January?

Comment: Change the dif examination to `dif_days = date_range_sales_start  - lag(date_range_sales_end);`.  The version of the same, that does NOT have a missing values NOTE:, would be `dif_days = -sum (-date_range_sales_start, lag(date_range_sales_end));`.  `dif_days` could be renamed `gap_days` to be more clear.